# Determing folio number from demat account

Tags: india, portfolio

I am holding the shares of Cauvery Software Engineering Systems LTD. in my demat account but I do not know the folio number and the serial numbers of the share of the company. Can anyone help me in finding out the folio and serial numbers of the shares? I intend to advise the board of directors to reimburse me the liquidation amount.

Comment: You mean a "demat account"? Does that mean you are in India?

Comment: I have edited your question making the above assumptions.  If they are incorrect please edit it back.

Answer (score 0):

The Demat statement should give you the details.